# Associated products not showing up in frontend in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

working with Magento 1.5.1 my grouped products don't show their associated products in the frontend (the list with their prices), however everything is fine on the backend and the other type of products (Simple and configurable) are ok in frontend.

It just don't load the grouped.phtml file, how could I debug the page loading process ? or even better, any ideas how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an extension that overwrites the grouped product generation file and it created a conflict.

After commenting a code line in its .xml, everything's back to normal.